# Is there a formula for the big radius of an evenly spaced ring of circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

You have n circles. The circles are arranged in a ring such that they are tangent to each other. the figure will have n-symmetry, that is, a ring of 3 circles can be rotated 120 degs and not change, 4-circle ring can be rotated 90 degs and not change, etc.

[image]

d is the diameter of one circle and R is the "Big Radius" of the entire figure, starting at the geometric center and ending at the edge of one circle such that the max length is had.

What I want to know is, **is there a forumla relating R with d and n?** If so I will be able to calculate it quickly for any n-cirlce ring rather than having to make constructions. As it is I just did it for n = 2 and n = 6 since those were the easiest.

**Note:** There are no circles inside the middle, not even as you go higher like n = 7, 8, 9, etc. It is a ring only, so this is technically **not** circle packing. The case of n = 6 is special since you could perfectly fit a 7th circle right in the middle, and in fact that is how I figured out what R should be. But it is coincidence only.

Comment: @achillehui Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @achill hui Yes, your "comment" plainly deserves to become an "answer" that does not need to be proved (up to the OP !)

Comment: The centers of the circles lie on the vertices of a regular polygon.  The length of the side of the regular polygon is d.  So if you know the expression for the distance from the center of a regular polygon to a vertex, just add d/2  to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the small circles' radius $r$. Then draw the right triangle whose vertices are

- the centre of the large ring
- the centre of one small circle; this has the right angle
- one of the two contacts of that small circle

The angle at the large ring centre is $\frac\pi n$ and the opposite side is $r$. Thus the hypotenuse is $\frac r{\sin\pi/n}$, and this is the "big radius" $R$ minus $r$, so
$$R=r\left(1+\frac1{\sin\pi/n}\right)=\frac d2\left(1+\frac1{\sin\pi/n}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. Apparently there is another equally way of doing it by the apothem but you explained this with trig so I accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you denote $r$ the radius of the circle on which the centres of the $n$ small circles lie, and $a$ the apothem of the regular polygon made up by these centres, we have
$$R=r+\frac a2=r\Bigl(1+\sin\frac{2\pi}n\Bigr).$$